# How to convert sum of terms in a vector in Julia?

Tags: julia

Do you know how to convert a sum of terms in a vector in Julia?

For instance, If we have a polynomial `p(x,y)=1 +x+y+xy+x^2+y^2+xy^4`, the array `v` associated to `p(x,y)` would be the following:

`v=[1,x,y,xy,x^2,y^2,xy^4]`

Other example: If you have the following expression: `a+b+c+abc+ac`, the array `v` associated to this expression would be the following:

`v=[a,b,c,abc,ac]`

Comment: You are describing the `TERMS(x)` function from yesteryears Derive symbolic language. I wonder what other CAS have something similar. [Derive help-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RLiZ.png) screenshot.

Comment: I think [metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/) is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup SymPy.jl if you want to learn how to do symbolic computation in Julia. Here is a reasonable tutorial: https://mth229.github.io/symbolic.html
Once you understand this, you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: The hot new (and native) package for symbolic computation in Julia is https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl  SymPy is old hat ;)

Comment: @DNF, how do you do what OP asked for with Symbolics.jl?

Answer (score 1):

Use [metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/) to parse the expression and look at the resulting expression tree

```
ex = Meta.parse("1 +x+y+x*y+x^2+y^2+x*y^4")
ex.args
8-element Vector{Any}:
  :+
 1
  :x
  :y
  :(x * y)
  :(x ^ 2)
  :(y ^ 2)
  :(x * y ^ 4)
```